# Understanding Shor algorithm fo Elliptic Curves Demonstration

Tags: quantum-algorithms, mathematics, shors-algorithm

I was reading [Shor's discrete logarithm quantum algorithm for elliptic curves](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301141). And i have two questions.

1. In page 7 they say that $x = (x0 - dy) mod q$, where $x0$ is between 0 and q-1, but then they replace $x = x0-dy$ which is not true.
   $x$ is a number between 0 and q-1 and the other expression is sometimes negative when $dy>x0$.
   Something similar happens later when they take $y' = dx' mod q$. My question is are they replacing for
   $$x = (x0 - dy) mod q $$
   $$y' = dx' mod q$$

and they simple don't put the mods, or for
$$x = x0 - dy $$
$$y' = dx'$$

The second ones are not always true because if $dy>x0$ you get a negative $x$ and $dx'$ sometimes is bigger that q while $y'$ is between 0 and q-1.

If is the first one can someone tell me how the sum is done because the paper simple say "The sum over y is easy to calculate", but you end up with mods in the exponents and i don't know how to solve it.

2. In the same page it says that $x0 =(x + dy ) mod q$, which is true, but it's also true that for some $d1$ you have that
   $x1 =(x + d1y ) mod q$, now replace $x$ for, $x = x1- d1y$,
   and continue with the same logic from the paper and you get that $d1 = y'(x')^{-1} mod q$. Why is this wrong?

Comment: please have a look at https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation for how to format math in posts and edit the question accordingly. That significantly improves readability

Comment: also, without opening the paper, a quick comment is that it is common in this context to assume without saying it explicitly that sums refers to modular operations, especially if $x$ and $y$ are here lables in a ket state.